# How to calculate height of a tableviewcell with right/left detail style?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have a `UITableView` with prototype cells in right/left detail style. The text length of both (multiline) labels varies pretty much.

This means that the width of the labels will change in regard to the text (even within the same section).

In a more general sense, this question applies to all cells containing at least 2 labels which are aligned horizontally to each other.

Is it possible to calculate the resulting cell height (in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`) without a given constraining label width?

I would like to layout the text in as few lines as possible = minimizing the cell height (see picture).

[image]

Any suggestions/solutions are appreciated!

Comment: Have an upvote. Please add pictures .)

Comment: Thanks. Picture is up.

Answer (score 1):

The height for the row is calculated in tableview delegate's method `- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

This is where you have to calculate the possible width & height of labels. It is possible to do by using `[@"LOOOONG TEXT" sizeWithFont:defaultFont];` Then just do the appropriate math and return needed height for the cell.

Comment: Ok, that's basically what I'm doing. The challenge is that the widths of the textLabel and the detailTextLabel are influencing each other: in my example (3rd cell) one could have squeezed one cell into one line, but resulting in the other label having >=3 lines.
Usually the solution for such problems is iteration: varying both label widths, calculating the resulting label heights, repeat these steps until BOTH label heights level on the same (minimized) value.

I was wondering whether this is a feasible approach (performance!?!?) or whether there is a template/demo code to achieve this goal.

Comment: I believe the new autolayout feature is used for this. If that's the case (iOS6 and up) you shouldn't worry about calculations. It is done for you based on the constraints you provide (minimal width of label, minimal distance between labels, etc.)

Comment: I'm using autolayout and it does adapt the labels' sizes. But as far I can say from testing the size adaption happens after the cells' sizes a calculated. This in turn means that I don't have any information about the final label sizes/widths when doing the math in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`.
So how to work around this?

I'm wondering that I am the only one trying to solve this problem. It seems to me to be a pretty common task...

Comment: If I use `sizeWithFont:` instead of `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` all cell heights get calculated as if the labels were 1-lined, no matter how long the text is/how many lines it has. Guessing the constrainedToSize doesn't make much sense since in most cases the guess won't match the label's final width, and therefore the calculated cell height might be wrong...